# PayPal ignores response to instant update callback

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

PayPal is ignoring the response to my instant update callback.

- I'm on sandbox
- I'm getting the callback
- I'm returning the *exact* example result in the documentation
- ...and PayPal continues to show my default shipping fee

Here's what I return from the callback (the example response at the end of [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/)):

`METHOD=CallbackResponse&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS Next Day Air&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=20.00&L_TAXAMT0=2.20&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=1.51&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=UPS Express 2 Days&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=10.00&L_TAXAMT1=2.00&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT1=1.35&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=UPS Ground2 to 7 Days&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=9.99&L_TAXAMT2=1.99&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT2=1.28&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false`

I've also tried a much simpler response with no change in effect:

`L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=20.00&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Standard+Domestic&METHOD=CallbackResponse`

What could I possibly be doing wrong? I see the callback in my server log. This is baffling.

Comment: Any website to check ?

Comment: Sure. POST anything at all to http://sandbox.gearlaunch.com/api/_paypal/instantUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in the response from the above url one parameter is missing which is "L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=somenamehere" .

Try updating your callback script to send the above variable also in the response to the PayPal and see if that works for you .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - that value is present: `$ curl --data '' http://sandbox.gearlaunch.com/api/_paypal/instantUpdate` yields `L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=20.00&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Standard+Domestic&METHOD=CallbackResponse`

Comment: So sorry , I mistakenly put the wrong variable , I just updated the post with the correct missing parameter

Comment: Wow, that worked! That field is completely undocumented!?!? Not only is it unmentioned on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/ but a google search of site:paypal.com L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0 turns up zero hits. How did you know this and what on earth is going on at PayPal?

Comment: This worked. Same opinion of stickfigure. Paypal should provide a workable example! I can't even imagine how did Eshan find out about the label option as it doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the callback response!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone interested, here is the documentation of the "Callback Response Message". I was also searching for the documentation because of a missing parameter.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/Callback_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)?.